# 'Web application could not be started', Porque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Estou a passar o meu projecto para o servidor. Estou a utiliar o nginx. E está tudo instalado já, pois quando vou ao meu endereço inicial mostra-me:

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx
```

No entanto, quando faço endereçoinicial/funbase, sendo que funbase é onde está o meu projecto ele mostra-me:

```
Web application could not be started
It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run: bundle install
If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following: 



   Is this app supposed to be run as the funbase user?
    Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.

-------- The exception is as follows: -------
git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first. (Bundler::GitError)

  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:192:in `rescue in load_spec_files'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:189:in `load_spec_files'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:92:in `local_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:159:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:53:in `__materialize__'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.9.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:278:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:381:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:157:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'

Error ID
    8febf14e
Application root
    /home/funbase
```

O meu projecto está em /home/funbase. E já fiz o bundle install, não estou a perceber porque não está a funcionar.

Comment: Qual versão do Passenger você está usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema pode ter algumas soluções tenta dar uma olhada [aqui](http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=505)

Tente rodar esse código `bundle install --deployment`

Ou este aqui `bundle pack`

Tem esses dois casos aqui que parecem ser iguais ao seu [caso1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648870/is-not-checked-out-bundle-install-does-not-fix-help) [caso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494399/deploying-rails3-apps-with-bundler-and-phusion-passenger-bundle-dir-not-found)

[]'s