# Erro ao inicializar minha aplicação em Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, servidor

Minha aplicação já estava rodando a algum tempo sem problemas, eu mesmo configurei o ambiente em uma máquina virtual. Tive que parar o servidor e quando eu fui startar novamente tive esse surpresinha.

Abaixo imagem com o erro gerado.

uninitialized constant Rails::Application::YAML (NameError)
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:377:in `secrets'
  /var/www/nginx/bday.advance.local/config/environments/production.rb:72:in`block in '
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in`configure'
  /var/www/nginx/bday.advance.local/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:598:in`block (2 levels) in '
...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Marconi, esse erro é retornado pelo servidor, ele está ativo. Vlw

Comment: Sim entendi, estou usando o Nginx com Passenger. Conhece?

Comment: Olha se pode te ajudar.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58179/web-application-could-not-be-started-porque

Comment: Qual a versão do rails e ruby?

Comment: - ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: É rvm? Rbenv ou o ruby da máquina mesmo?

Comment: Sim é rvm. Um companheiro de um grupo sugeriu que eu instalasse safe_yaml e rodou. O que eu achei estranho é que a app já tava rodando sem isso. De repente veio a surpresa.

Comment: Cara posta o código do teu `application.rb`. O problema está nesse `safe_yaml` que você instalou, verifica se você deu um `require 'yaml'` por exemplo no teu `application.rb`.

Comment: Parece mesmo que o erro tá no application.rb. Remove esse safe_yaml pelo menos para testar. Refaz os passos inversos.